# .NET Winforms Chart not refresh on property modified

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have this code example:

```
var chartArea = new ChartArea("chartArea");
chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = -500;
chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
chart.Series.Add(someSeries);
...
(later on execution)
chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
chart.Update();
chart.Refresh();
```

The chart doesn't redraw (no new AxisX limit apear).

EDIT: No exception thrown. Just the form loading and after run this code, no chart area appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you added some values to the chart? Try add at least one.

Comment: Seems the chart area doesn't show if has no value...:)

Comment: Yes, but the old axis also can't have shown. So your question was very incomplete and misleading!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your chartarea is connected to some series otherwise it's not displayed.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ChartArea _myArea;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _myArea = new ChartArea("chartArea");
            _myArea.AxisX.Minimum = -500;            
            chart1.ChartAreas.Add(_myArea);
            chart1.Series.FirstOrDefault().ChartArea = "chartArea"; //comment this line and behavior reproduced
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _myArea.AxisX.Minimum = _myArea.AxisX.Minimum - 50;            
            chart1.Update();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I missed this, but in my code the series is connected with chart area...I added at least one value (data point) and then the chart showed up, i will try to find the property which makes the chart area appear with 0 values.